# Error in PSTricks package

Tags: errors, pstricks, compilation-error

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
Test.
\end{document}
```

I compile my document using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`.

When I come to the second step in the compilation process (`dvips <filename>`), I get the following error:

> `dvips: ! Couldn't find header file: l3backend-dvips.pro`

How do I fix this?

I have a feeling that the problem is related to [`pst-eucl`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-eucl) but I'm not sure, since I haven't tested it with other PSTricks packages.

**Update**

Here is the output I get from running the commands that Phelype Oleinik asks for:

```
[<username>@localhost ~]$ tlmgr info l3backend --list
tlmgr: cannot find package l3backend, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `l3backend' in their title/description:

Packages containing files matching `l3backend':
```

The command `kpsewhich -a l3backend-dvips.pro` doesn't give any output.

Comment: Do you use MiKTeX or TeXLive? You need to make sure the `l3backend` package is installed. In my up-to-date TeXLive 2019 it works.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I  use TeX Live 2019. I've just updated the system and it didn't help. Are you also compiliing using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf`?

Comment: Yes, and the `dvips` run finds the `l3backend` file correctly ([terminal output](https://pastebin.com/K0WD9wZ3)). Can you please show me the output of `tlmgr info l3backend --list` and of `kpsewhich -a l3backend-dvips.pro`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik See updated question.

Comment: Right, that's the problem. For some reason you don't have the `l3backend` package (thus `kpsewhich` returns nothing, and that's why `dvips` fails). I believe you have a non-full TeXLive scheme or something went wrong during the installation of `l3backend`. If it's the former, then `tlmgr install l3backend` should solve the problem. If it's the latter, `tlmgr install l3backend` should give a hint of what the problem is. Try that to see what happens

Comment: `[root@localhost <username>]# tlmgr install l3backend
tlmgr: package repository /usr/share/texlive (not verified: unknown)
tlmgr install: package l3backend not present in repository.
tlmgr: action install returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.`

Comment: You are installing from a local repository (at `/usr/share/texlive`), which doesn't seem to be up to date. Try (say) `tlmgr install -repository 'http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet' l3backend`. Though you will probably need to update `l3kernel`, `l3packages`, and `l3experimental` from the remote repository too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101685/discussion-between-svend-tveskaeg-and-phelype-oleinik).

Comment: run `tlmgr --self --all --repository=ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet`